# How to handle user input using os/exec in golang? I can't stop input stage

Tags: go

First, I build a command as exec.exe from this:

```golang
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    var input string
    fmt.Println("input a value")
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    fmt.Println(input)

    fmt.Println("input another value")
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    fmt.Println(input)
}
```

Then I want to use os/exec pacage to run it:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("G:\\go_workspace\\GOPATH\\src\\pjx\\modules\\exec\\exec")

    stdin, e := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    stdout, e := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    if e:=cmd.Start();e!=nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    stdin.Write([]byte("hello"))
    var buf = make([]byte, 512)
    n, e := stdout.Read(buf)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(buf[:n]))

    if e := cmd.Wait(); e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

Finally I run it, and result will pause on the user input stage,like:

(in case picture is not loaded, they're paused on input stage)

```golang
please input a value:

1
12
232
```

[image: unexpected result, pausing on user input stage]

Did I use cmd pipe in a wrong way?

Comment: My first guess is that you need an newline character after `hello`, as scanln might be scanning for lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is blocking because the `fmt.Scanln` in the subprocess is waiting for the `\n` character (an `EOF` would also cause it to return). To avoid blocking, your input should include two `\n`s, or you can just call 'stdin.Close()' to indicate that the input stream is done.

And since the subprocess calls `Scanln` and `Println` multiple times, a single call to `stdout.Read` may not read the complete output from the subprocess. You can keep calling the `stdout.Read()` until an `io.EOF` error is returned, or just use the `ioutil.ReadAll`.

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("G:\\go_workspace\\GOPATH\\src\\pjx\\modules\\exec\\exec")

    stdin, e := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    stdout, e := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    if e := cmd.Start(); e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    _, e = stdin.Write([]byte("hello\nworld\n"))
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    stdin.Close()

    out, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout)
    // or you can use a loop
    //for {
    //  var buf = make([]byte, 512)
    //  n, e := stdout.Read(buf)
    //  if e == io.EOF {
    //      break
    //  }
    //  if e != nil {
    //      panic(e)
    //  }
    //  fmt.Println(string(buf[:n]))
    //}

    fmt.Println(string(out))

    if e := cmd.Wait(); e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: 3q, it helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to be listening to the output of the executing program. When you write "hello", the program is probably still writing to its stdout. Try this:

```
    go func() {
        in := bufio.NewReader(stdout)
        for {
            s, err := in.ReadString('\n')
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(s)
        }
    }()

    if e := cmd.Start(); e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    stdin.Write([]byte("hello\n"))
    stdin.Write([]byte("hello2\n"))
    if e := cmd.Wait(); e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
```

Comment: @fwhez fixed answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it

```
cmd := exec.Command("...") // Change to your path
stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
// read the stdout continuously in a separate goroutine and capture it in buf
go func() {
    io.Copy(buf, stdout)
}()

if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

stdin.Write([]byte("hello\n")) // Send \n to submit
stdin.Write([]byte("world\n"))

if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Fprint(os.Stdout, buf)
```

Result:

```
➜ go run main.go
input a value
hello
input another value
world
```

Comment: 3q, it helps a lot